# How do I fetch text blurbs using open refine 2.6?

Tags: freebase, openrefine

I am running a very simple exercise where I have a list of people's names that have been already reconciled via freebase, from within Open Refine.

The Github repository for Open Refine clearly indicates that fetching Properties against a reconciled Freebase Type is still a "To Do" project, but apparently, fetching text blurbs is possible..

> Starting from your reconciled column, use "Add column from Freebase"
>   and use the "Add a property" field at the top to add
>   /common/topic/article. - using the new column, select "Add a column by
>   fetching a URL" and construct the URL as follows:
>   "http://api.freebase.com/api/trans/raw"+value - You'll end up with
>   another new column containing the text of all the blurbs

I don't have an option "Add column from Freebase".

[image: No add column from Freebase]

Am I missing something? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's presumably OpenRefine 2.6 **beta** since the production release isn't out yet [emphasis added].

If *Add from Freebase* is missing, something is wrong (ie it's a bug).  Please file a bug report on [GitHub](http://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues) with information on what operating system you're using.  The documentation that you quoted is also out of date.  Please also file a bug report for it with the location you found it.

Sorry about the problem!  We'll have a look as soon as we've got the information from the bug report(s).

Comment: Yes, it is open refine 2.6 beta, for Mac. I'll try with the windows version, as well ans linux and I'll definitely file a bug report on GitHub. Thank you very much for all the great work Tom. Cheers.

Comment: For reference, the workaround from [the issue tracker](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/797#issuecomment-24886076) is to select a specific language from the main Refine screen - the missing text should then appear.